# Как сделать асинхронный ответ в Django?

Tags: django, asyncio

Необходимо отдать 204 ответ сервера не дожидаясь выполнения подпрограммы (django v3.1.5). Попытался сделать через asyncio

views.py

```
@sync_to_async
@csrf_exempt
@async_to_sync
async def product_update(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.create_task(do_somthing())

        print('---------------- 1 ----------------')
        return HttpResponse(status=204)
    else:
        HttpResponseForbidden()

async def do_somthing():
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print('---------------- 2 ----------------')
```

Но так не выполняется функция do_somthing(), в консоле только:

```
---------------- 1 ----------------
[16/Feb/2021 18:00:12] "POST /api/test/update/ HTTP/1.1" 204 0
```

Comment: попробуйте через `celery`

Comment: @5c0rp, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, взять какой-нибудь асинхронный фреймворк. Например, `dramatiq` (есть удобная имплементация - `django_dramatiq` - https://github.com/Bogdanp/django_dramatiq)

**tasks.py**

```
import dramatiq


@dramatiq.actor
def do_somthing():
    print("Async task")
```

**views.py**

```
@csrf_exempt
def product_update(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        do_somthing.send()
        return HttpResponse(status=204)
    else:
        HttpResponseForbidden()
```

Comment: Спасибо! Если не получится разобраться с asynio попробую.

Comment: Спасибо, библиотека интересная, но результат такой же **do_somthing()** не отрабатывает. Ошибок в консоли нет.

Comment: Не может такого быть. 1. Точно метод `POST`? 2. брокер настроили? 3. `worker` запустили?

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь! Может действительно вчера что-то забыл, но с утра запустил работает.